# Show $f$: $Z_{mn}\mapsto Z_{m}$ $\times$ $Z_{n}$ by the rule $f(x\pmod{mn}) = (x\pmod{m}, x\pmod{n})$ is a homomorphism.

Tags: ring-theory, ring-homomorphism

I defined a function from two rings $f$: $Z_{mn} \mapsto Z_{m}$ $\times$ $Z_{n}$ as $f(x\pmod{mn}) = (x\pmod{m}, x\pmod{n})$ and I want to show that it is a homomorphism.

Observe that for any $x,y \in Z_{mn}, f(x)= (x\pmod{m}, x\pmod{n})$. 
Similarly, $f(y)= (y\pmod{m}, y\pmod{n})$.

Now, $f(x)+f(y)=(x\pmod{m},x\pmod{n})+(y\pmod{m},y\pmod{n})$   (1)

= $(x\pmod{m}+y\pmod{m}),(x\pmod{n}+y\pmod{n})$   (2)

= $(x+y\pmod{m}),(x+y\pmod{n})$   (3)

= $f(x+y)$. (4)

Similarly for multiplication.

Observe that for any $x,y \in Z_{mn}, f(x)= (x\pmod{m}, x\pmod{n})$. 
Similarly, $f(y)= (y\pmod{m}, y\pmod{n})$.

Now, $f(x)f(y)=(x\pmod{m},x\pmod{n})*(y\pmod{m},y\pmod{n})$   (1)

= $(x\pmod{m}*y\pmod{m}),(x\pmod{n}+y\pmod{n})$   (2)

= $(xy\pmod{m}),(xy\pmod{n})$   (3)

= $f(xy)$. (4)

However, my book says that $x\pmod{n} + y\pmod{n} = (x+y\pmod{n})\pmod{n}$ and
$x\pmod{n} * y\pmod{n} = (xy\pmod{n})\pmod{n}$. But this is not what I need to justify step (2) to (3) so what am I doing wrong? Thank you.

Comment: You simply forgot that, in $\mathbf Z$, $x\bmod n+-y\bmod n$ may perfectly well be greater that $n$, hence the definition $$ x\bmod n+y\bmod n\overset{\text{def}}{=}(x\bmod n+y\bmod n)\bmod n. $$

Comment: Thank you for responding. But one question, wouldn't putting the doudle `\pmod{m}` make step (3) to (4) false because it is not the exact definition of the original function?

Comment: (4) should be written ${}=f\bigl((x+y)\bmod mn\bigr)$.

Comment: Oh okay I see it now. I made several notation errors. Thank you!

Comment: B. t.w., did you note the difference between `\bmod` and `\mod`, from a typographical point of view?

Comment: `\bmod` does not have an extra spacing? Yes. Sorry, I am new to the world of Latex.

Comment: It has a smaller spacing, but I mean that the difference is meaningful: for instance you can write $14\bmod 10=4$ (in other words it is the function which associates to a number the representative of its congruence class  in $[0,9]$, whereas you'll write $14\equiv 4\mod 10$ to denote the congruence *relation*.

Comment: Had not noticed. Thank you. Will use for future.